# How to change the pixel quality and size of Image using Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, pixel

I have a list of image URLs and I want to get all those images which are more than 14Mb in size or 14 Megapixel in quality and resize them to under 5Mb in size and 10 Megapixel in quality. I used [Image library](https://github.com/tanaikech/ImgApp) provided by @Tanaike on Github to manipulate image size and quality.

Here is the code snippet to download the image as a blob and check its size and dimension using `ImgApp` library:

```
 funtion CompressImage() {

    var url = "http://images.salsify.com/image/upload/s--PyaEswlb
--/f595bd4e42783097f42e4615e17024b6b82da014.jpg";

      var folderId = "Your Folder ID";
      var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
 
      var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
      var fileBlob = response.getBlob()
 
   
      var res = ImgApp.getSize(fileBlob);
   
       
       if((res.filesize/1000000)>14 || res.width>14000000)
       {
       
         ProcessImage(fileBlob , folder);
       
       }
}
```

The If statement in the above code checks the file size and pixel quality, if it is above the threshold (14Mb size, 14 Megapixel quality) then it executes the `ProcessImage` function. This function sets the width size, and replaces the old image with the newly resized image.

```
  function ProcessImage(fileBlob,folder) 

  {
   
  var width = 3600; // Please set the size of width with the unit of pixels.
  var file = folder.createFile(fileBlob);

  var fileId = file.getId();
  var link = Drive.Files.get(fileId).thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s.+/, "=s" + width);
  var blob2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link).getBlob().setName("Compressed Image");
  var file = folder.createFile(blob2);
  
  var img = Drive.Files.get(file.getId()).webContentLink; //get the view link of image downloaded in drive
  Logger.log(img);
  Drive.Files.remove(fileId); 
    
   }
```

The above two functions combine to get the resized image which is less than 14 Mb in size but I am not able to change the pixel quality of the image (less than 14 Megapixel). Can you please guide what am I doing wrong? Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is `the pixel quality of the image`?

Comment: I am not fully aware of how to get this using your library because you termed image height and width as pixels. That's why I thought that changing width of image would also reduce the pixels in image

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand `the pixel quality of the image` and your current issue and your goal. And also, I cannot understand `That's why I thought that changing width of image would also reduce the pixels in image`. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Comment: yes, so first function from above checks the image size and quality, second function resize it. I have been able to reduce the size of image but I also want to change the pixels in image. I am not sure how to check or reduce pixels in image. So my question is how to reduce pixels in image e.g 14 Megapixel to 5 Megapixel?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Can I ask you about the detail of `but I also want to change the pixels in image.`? For example, can you provide the sample image for testing your situation?

Comment: Yes, I have added an image link in the first function. There you can view the image.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From `I have added an image link in the first function. There you can view the image`, I tested your script. But, unfortunately, the image cannot be downloaded. Can you confirm it again?

Comment: Thank you for replying. I tested your showing URL of `http://images.salsify.com/image/upload/s--PyaEswlb-/f595bd4e42783097f42e4615e17024b6b82da014.jpg` by removing the line break. Unfortunately, I cannot download the image. I apologize for this.

Comment: Here is a link to sheet which has some image links:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iiEI0TsmZMnIagi4LbJyXqY97Ao6X6SP4FGVNW7QgwU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your provided URLs, I could test your script. But I cannot still understand `the pixel quality of the image` and `but I also want to change the pixels in image.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: @Tanaike, the image url in the first function is working now. Thank you

Comment: Ok, when I try to upload image in an online platform, it gives error that your image is above 15 Megapixel, that's why I want to reduce it to 10 Megapixel or may be 5 Megapixel just like we are able to change image size by changing it's width in second function. In short, I want to reduce the quality of image so that it can be uploaded without any error.

Comment: For example, when your 1st URL is used, the image size is changed from 4480x4480 to 3600x3600. From `it gives error that your image is above 15 Megapixel, that's why I want to reduce it to 10 Megapixel or may be 5 Megapixel just like we are able to change image size by changing it's width in second function.`, in this case, for example, when your script is used, how about modifying from `var width = 3600;` to `var width = 2000;`? But I cannot still understand `the pixel quality of the image`. I apologize for my poor English skill.

Comment: yes, that can be an option as I just want to confirm whether changing the width would reduce the quality of the image?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, for example, you want to convert an image of 4480x4480 to an image of 2000x2000 with lower quality. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: yes, right. The image quality should be reduced. Would it mean the reduction in pixels also, right?

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your replying, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to reduce the image size from 4480x4480 to 2000x2000. At this time, you want to reduce the lower quality of the image.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

### Issue and workaround:

I thought that in this case, for example, when you want to reduce the image size from 4480x4480 to 2000x2000, the following flow can achieve your goal.

1. Reduce the image from 4480x4480 to 100x100.
2. Increase the image from 100x100 to 2000x2000.

By this, the image quality can be reduced by keeping the size. But, unfortunately, the method using `thumbnailLink` cannot increase the image. By this, it is required to use another workaround.

In this answer, I would like to propose another workaround for changing the image size.

### Usage

#### 1. Install Google Apps Script library.

As one more Google Apps Script library, please install [DocsServiceApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp). You can see how to install it at [here](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp#how-to-install).

#### 2. Sample script.

When your script is used, the modified script is as follows. In this case, I modified your function `ProcessImage`.

```js
// Please run this function.
function CompressImage() {
  var url = "http://images.salsify.com/image/upload/s--54TepGAl--/2f76d5ec5400b654b6f3dbd068db7898a76389cf.jpg";
  var folderId = "root";
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url)
  var fileBlob = response.getBlob()
  var res = ImgApp.getSize(fileBlob);
  if ((res.filesize / 1000000) > 14 || res.width > 14000000) {
    ProcessImage(fileBlob, folder);
  }
}

function ProcessImage(fileBlob, folder) {
  var width1 = 100; // Please adjust this value.
  var width2 = 2000; // Please adjust this value.

  // Create original image as a file.
  var file1 = folder.createFile(fileBlob);
  var fileId1 = file1.getId();

  // Reduce original image size.
  var link1 = Drive.Files.get(fileId1).thumbnailLink.replace(/\=s.+/, "=s" + width1);

  // Increase converted image size.
  const object = { title: "temp", parent: "root", width: { unit: "pixel", size: width2 }, height: { unit: "pixel", size: width2 } };
  const sId = DocsServiceApp.createNewSlidesWithPageSize(object);
  const s = SlidesApp.openById(sId);
  const slide = s.getSlides()[0];
  slide.insertImage(link1).setWidth(width2 / 1.33333).setHeight(width2 / 1.33333);
  s.saveAndClose();

  // Retrieve result image.
  const link2 = Slides.Presentations.Pages.getThumbnail(sId, slide.getObjectId(), { "thumbnailProperties.thumbnailSize": "LARGE" }).contentUrl;
  var blob2 = UrlFetchApp.fetch(link2).getBlob().setName("Compressed Image");
  var file2 = folder.createFile(blob2);
  var img = Drive.Files.get(file2.getId()).webContentLink;
  Logger.log(img);

  Drive.Files.remove(fileId1);
  Drive.Files.remove(sId);
}
```

- **IMPORTANT**: In this workaround, as an important point, by the current specification of Slides API, the output image size can be selected only 3 patterns like `LARGE` (The thumbnail image width of 1600px.), `MEDIUM` (The thumbnail image width of 800px.), `SMALL` (The thumbnail image width of 200px.). I think that this is the bottleneck of this workaround.
- When this script is run, the image size of the original image is converted from 4480x4480 to 100x100 using `thumbnailLink`. And, the image of 100x100 is converted to 2000x2000 using DocsServiceApp and Google Slides. And, when an image is exported from Google Slides, an image with low quality with 1600x1600 is obtained.

### Note:

- `100x100` and `2000x2000` are the sample sizes. So, please modify the values of `var width1 = 100;` and `var width2 = 2000;` for your actual situation. By this, you can control the quarity of the image.

### Reference:

- [DocsServiceApp](https://github.com/tanaikech/DocsServiceApp)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I ran the script, and I changed the values of ```width1 and width2```,  size is changed but the quality remained the same, as well as the colour of the image, also became dull. Can we enhance the quality of the image by keeping the size consistent (400KB, 500KB)?

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About `Can we enhance the quality of the image by keeping the size consistent (400KB, 500KB)?`, how about adjusting `var width1 = 100;`? For example, it's `var width1 = 500;` and `var width1 = 1000;`? But, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand `Can we enhance the quality of the image by keeping the size consistent (400KB, 500KB)?`. If I misunderstood it, I apologize.

Comment: I changed ```width1 = 1000 and width2 = 2000```, the size of the image is now 6Mb but the quality and colour of image became really dull.

Comment: Here is the new image link: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Giie-VRuzPxxSuADpNpRi7ccpBvBf0ag/view?usp=sharing

This is old image link:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CE2nePwvCd69aF1Ci2y2z494fApHknKo/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I think that the adjustment is required in this case. For example, how about `var width1 = 400;` and `var width2 = 4000;`?

Comment: ```var width1 = 400;```. and ```var width2 = 4000;```. Thank you. This imporved the color of image

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. About `This imporved the color of image`, unfortunately, I think that this is the current specification for the image on Google Slides. Unfortunately, I have no information about another workaround for modifying this situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Comment: Thank you, you have already been great help.

Comment: @Roomi Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor skill, again. I would like to study more and more.